# How to create an object in which the object itself is a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object from which I created from a constructor.

```
var obj = new Obj();
```

It has several functions but I wish to also use it as follows;

```
obj();
```

Obj is defined as:

```
function obj() {
   this.blah = function () {
   };
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Functions are objects, so you can create a function and add properties to it. What you can't do, is create an object, and magically turn it into a function

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to have a function you call which returns an arbitrary function that is treated as both an object and a function. Each one would be unique, and you would not need to use `new`.

```
function Obj() {
 var ret = function(){
  console.log('Hello');
 };
 ret.blah = function () {
   console.log('World');
 };
 return ret;
}

var obj = Obj();

obj();//Hello
obj.blah();//World
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create properties on function objects. For instance, if you have the function

```
function foo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

You can set a property on `foo`.

```
foo.baz = 42;
```

So now you can call `foo` and get the result `"bar"`, and you can access its `baz` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for 'closure' here.
Try:

```
function MyObject(/* constructor params */) {
   //assign properties to 'this'
   return function() {
      return this;  //<== placeholder implementation
   }.bind(this);
}
var obj1 = new MyObject();
```

Now if you do `console.log(obj1)` you will see `function() { [...] }` and you will be able to do `obj1()` to execute your function.

As a bonus in the code above, I also added `this` binding in the 'closure' as you will need it in most cases that you are doing anything interesting.